# Error: Syntax error. Missing ')' in formula salesforce

Tags: validation-rule

I am new to the validation rules on salesforce and I need help.

the need is If all these fields are different from null then = 1

I have a problem of parenthesis

Thanks for your help

```
if( 
(Street != null ),
AND(City != null),
AND(PostalCode != null), 
AND( (NumberOfEmployees or AnnualRevenue ) !=null),
AND(Industry_Code_Text__c != null ),
AND(Phone != null) = 1)
```

Comment: This goes deeper than a simple issue with parenthesis. There are several syntax and conceptual errors here. If you haven't done so already, you should go through the [Formulas and Validations](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic) module on Trailhead. Trailhead is _the_ place to get an introduction to things you aren't familiar with on the Salesforce platform.

Comment: After you've gone through that module, take a step back and think about _what field needs to have the value `1`_? Validation rules don't set field values, they prevent bad data by preventing a record from being inserted or updated (when the validation rule results in `true`). If you need to set a field value, then you either need a formula field or a record-triggered flow.

Answer (score 0):

`AND` takes an arbitrary number of parameters, each being a Boolean value, according to the normal logic.

```
AND(cond1, cond2, cond3, ...)
```

Similarly, `OR` is used to check if at least one condition is true:

```
OR(cond1, cond2, cond3, ...)
```

While, as we can say in English, "if a or b is true," this is not something found in most programming languages. You must be explicit by saying "if a is true or b is true."

In addition, an `IF` requires exactly three parameters:

```
IF(cond, valueWhenTrue, valueWhenFalse)
```

You would need to determine what the value should be for when the conditions are not met.

It seems that you may have seen something like:

```
CASE(field, cond1, 1, cond2, 1, cond3, 1, 0) = 1
```

This is only applicable to the `CASE` function that works around the limitation that `CASE` cannot return a TRUE or FALSE value, it can only return certain data types. You do not need this hack for your situation.

However, it does not seem that you need the `IF` statement at all.

Validation rules accept either TRUE or FALSE (not 1 or 0, or any other variant), where the rule is triggered if the result is true.

The Best Practice regarding validation rules is that each field should be validated independently. This allows the UI to provide red boxes with the related error message on each field to complete, which is a great UX (User Experience).

In other words, you should have **seven** validation rules.

As a single validation rule, it would look like this:

```
AND(
    Street != null,
    City != null,
    PostalCode != null,
    NumberOfEmployees != null,
    AnnualRevenue != null,
    Industry_Code_Text__c != null,
    Phone != null
)
```

Again, I cannot stress this enough, do not do this. Make it seven different validation rules, one for each field. They will still take the same amount of time to execute, but will provide better errors for the users.